# beginDelayedTransiton in RecyclerView ViewHolder is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, transition, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

I am trying to animate `RecyclerView` items using `ConstraintSet` animation.
I have two layouts and they are switched properly using this code:

```
val constraint2 = ConstraintSet()
constraint2.clone(binding.root.context, R.layout.list_item_2)

val transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = OvershootInterpolator(1.0f)
transition.duration = 1200
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.root.container, transition)

constraint2.applyTo(binding.root.container)
```

However delayed transition is completely ignored and it works the same way whether or not I add `beginDelayedTransition` code, so there is no animation.

Comment: when are you invoking the animation

Comment: in onBindViewHolder

Comment: It will never work in `onBindViewHolder` because at that point `ViewHolder` is not part of the layout yet so it's not possible to perform transition. You could try to do it `onAttachedToWindow` but I'm not sure if that won't cause other issues.